# How to dynamically load and call a function in a BPL package

Tags: delphi

It seems pretty straightforward but the code below doesn't work.

BPL:

```
procedure DoSomething();
begin
  LogEvent('Did');
end;

exports
  DoSomething;
```

Main EXE:

```
procedure CallModuleFunc;
var
  H: THandle;
  P: procedure();
begin
  H := LoadPackage('mymod.bpl');
  try
    if (H <> 0) then
    begin
      @P := GetProcAddress(H, 'DoSomething');
      if Assigned(P) then
        P();
    end;
  finally
    UnloadPackage(H);
  end;
end;
```

Now there's no error, the bpl loads successfully with `LoadPackage()` but `GetProcAddress()` returns nil. Why? probably because name mangling. I've tried adding `stdcall` (both exported function and `P`'s declaration) but that didn't solve the problem. I've seen hundreds of examples on the web that it's supposed to be working this way. I even tried `GetProcAddress(H, 'DoSomething$qqsv')` but it didn't work either. What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried your code on Delphi XE7 and it works. Does your project has been compiled using the same Delphi version used to compile the package? If it's not, I'm not sure but I think it will not work.

Comment: That's not how to export functionality from a package. Packages work best when linked implicitly. If you want to expose functionality as you demonstrate here use a DLL. Mostly though people separate code into modules and introduce complexity and problems where none are needed. Put all your code into one executable.

Comment: Use Delphi's command-line [TDUMP.EXE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility) utility to see the *exact* name that is being exported, and then you can copy that name into your `GetProcAddress()` call.

Comment: Thanks to @FabFab I realized the problem was not about the naming, mangling or calling convention but about where the BPL file is put into.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sometimes you need to use packages with dynamic load (or implied). For example if you are using something similar to a system plugiuns.
You can not always load a package implicitly, you can not always use DLL's.

Comment: @Neftalí I understand that. I also know that in a great many situations people use packages when they don't need to and thus create extra hurdles.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's also true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searches and trial and errors, I realized it had to be about something I do or did differently. The problem was that my very first version of mymod.bpl was put into Delphi's default BPL output directory (which had no export, no DoSomething() at all). Then, I had changed the BPL output directory to my project's root source directory, so that I could see the sources and the bpl modules in one place. The exe was not put into where the sources reside as it used to be in Delphi 7, it was under Debug or Release folders. What misdirecting me was that when LoadPackage() cannot find the module in exe's current dir (which was Debug/Release) it looks at Delphi's default package folder (which had the very first and wrong version of the bpl) and loads it, so no error there but also no DoSomething() because it was no longer updated by my module's compile.

I hope this explanation helps someone else who might have a similar issue to figure things out. Thanks to everyone who spared time to read this and written comments.

Comment: @dummzeuch Too late for that really. This falls under the off topic close vote as *a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error*. But strangely it has been reopened so that more nonsense answers can be added, and this answer bearing no relation to the question garners two upvotes. Really, this sort of behaviour where we encourage poor questions isn't helpful for the quality of the site.

Comment: This code works fine with some considerations.

(1) Put the BPL on the same directory of the EXE file or use complete path in LoadLibrary.
(2) Don't use stdcall.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late, but I would like present a Solution of mine, which depend on ChatGPT Prompt:

First, you have to open a new BPL-Project. Then you can write your Code in a BPLUnit.pas (class'es, Function's, Procedure's, ...).
For this, the best practice is, to write a "Interface".
Interface's don't support Constructor's, Destructor's, virtual, and abstract Function's, and Procedure's).

Here comes Code for Delphi, which shows, how your Interface unit can be coded:

```
unit Interfaces;
interface

type
  PointerByte = ^Byte;

type
  IRF_Package = interface(IInterface)
    ['{12345678-1234-1234-1234-CAFEBABE0000}']
    function DeCompressBuffer(str: String; len: Integer): Boolean;
    function DeCompressAll: Boolean;
  end;

implementation
end.
```

and this is the Interface implementation Code (the BPL Project Code):

```
unit ImplInterface;
interface
uses
  Windows, Classes, SysUtils, Dialogs, Interfaces;
type
  TRF_Package = class(TInterfacedObject, IRF_Package)
  public
    function DeCompressBuffer(str: String; len: Integer): Boolean;
    function DeCompressAll: Boolean;

    constructor Create; overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TRF_Package.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  <your code logic>
end;

destructor TRF_Package.Destroy;
begin
  <your code logic>
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TRF_Package.DeCompressBuffer(
  str: String;
  len: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  <your code logic>
  result := true;
end;
function TRF_Package.DeCompressAll: Boolean;
begin
  <your code logic>
  result := true;
end;

end.
```

Now, you can use the Interface (in EXE Project):

```
procedure InterfaceProcedureInAPPcode;
var
  MyPackage : IRF_Package;
  MyGUID    : TGUID;

  procedure LoadBPL;
  var
    H: HModule;
  begin
    H := 0;
    try
      try
        H := LoadPackage('Package.bpl');
        if H = 0 then
        begin
          raise Exception.Create(
          #10 + 'Can not load package: Package.bpl' +
          #10 + 'aborted.');
        end;

        MyGUID := StringToGUID(
        '{12345678-1234-1234-1234-CAFEBABE0000}');
        MyPackage := CreateComObject( MyGUID ) as IRF_Package;

        if not Assigned(MyPackage) then
        begin
          raise Exception.Create(
          'can not access Interface: IRF_Package');
        end;

        if not(MyPackage.DeCompressAll) then
        begin
          raise Exception.Create(
          'bpl error.');
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage('Exception:' +
          #10 + E.CLassName +
          #10 + E.Message  );
        end;
      end;
    finally
      UnloadPackage(H);
    end;
  end;
begin
  LoadBPL;
end;
```

With this Code, you don't need use the "export" keyword.

I hope I could help a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

See below a piece of code.
It's running under Delphi XE3.

```
// Package declaration
package Package1;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl;

contains
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

end.
```

The unit Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface
uses Vcl.Forms;

procedure Test(); stdcall;

exports
   Test;

implementation

procedure Test();
var F : TForm;
begin
  F := TForm.Create(nil);
  F.ShowModal;
  F.Release;
end;

end.
```

The Project for testing bpl.
Contains only one Tform with one TButton.
(Package1.bpl is in the same directory of project1.exe)

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
   TProcTest = procedure;
var
   PackageModule: HModule;
   proc : TProcTest;
begin
  PackageModule := LoadPackage('Package1.bpl');
  if PackageModule <> 0 then
  begin
    @Proc := GetProcAddress( PackageModule, 'Test' );
    if @Proc <> nil then
      Proc;
    UnloadPackage(PackageModule);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This does not remotely answer the question. Furthermore, you use `register` calling convention on one side, and `stdcall` on the other. They have to match. Not that it matters for a no-arg function, but you seem to be mistaken in believing that `stdcall` is just something that you use when exporting.

Answer (score -2):

You must have to add stdCall in your declaration.

```
procedure DoSomething();stdcall;
begin
  LogEvent('Did');
end;

exports
  DoSomething;
```

Comment: Absolutely not. Now the two function prototypes differ. What matters is not which calling convention is chosen but that the same calling convention is used.

Comment: Hello @DavidHeffernan: For C/C++ I have to use "cdecl" ? I ask, because in C++ Builder, you can see "__fastcall" in mostly all TForm Packages.

Comment: @jens You don't have to use any single specific calling convention. You just have to make sure that both sides of the interface use the same one.