# Is there any way to load a unit dynamically in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

When an application is already running (runtime), is it possible to dynamically load a .pas file and use it?

Comment: No, they need to be compiled into *.dcu files. But you can search for Pascal scripting tools.

Comment: You can try DWScript (Delphi Web Script). Delphi itself is not a scripting language - it's a compiled language. But there's nothing stopping you from rolling out a scripting option in your application. I've done such a thing actually, where a user can write pascal script to draw graphics.

Comment: But depending on your purpose, you might also consider using DLLs or Packages.

Answer (score 6):

### Not directly, no.

A `.pas` file must be compiled into a `.dcu` file and linked into an executable (program or library) before it can then be executed at runtime.

If you need to load and execute the code dynamically, you can compile the unit into a runtime Package (bpl) first, and then load that file at runtime using the [`LoadPackage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.LoadPackage) function.  See the following articles for more details:

[Loading Packages in an Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Loading_Packages_in_an_Application)

[Loading Packages with the LoadPackage Function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Loading_Packages_with_the_LoadPackage_Function)

[Dynamic packages in Delphi](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178)

[How to dynamically load and call a function in a BPL package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430980/)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to compile it into the program?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not if it is supposed to be used like a runtime plugin, for instance.

Comment: He asked how to load and execute code from a .pas file at runtime. You've told him how to do something else.

Comment: In fact, the question was quite general, and gave way to different interpretations. That was the purpose anyway, because the intention was just to know if there was such a possibility of functionality within Delphi, somehow. My real intentions are, starting from a unit repository, where these units have classes from the same interface, dynamically loading and executing them (through the interface call). However, I already knew that the principle was confusing because it was a compiled code.

Comment: I actually created a dynamic compiler. I can not dynamically load the unit, but I can create a project, add those units in the project, and use msbuild to generate the program, which does what I need. In the end, the result would be the same, because you could at any time change these units and "load them dynamically", that is, compile software containing them and trigger their functionality. Although functional, at first, this approach runs sharply at licensing Delphi itself, because I would need the compiler, and it is not something that could accomplish the deploy easily.

Comment: Anyway, this remains valid, as theory. I do not know if other compilers like Free Pascal would bring some benefit to this approach. Anyway, sincere thanks for your attention.

Comment: @EdgarPavão what you describe is close to producing something like [PascalScript](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is no. Pascal is source code and cannot be executed directly. It must first be translated one way or another.

Comment: Had you asked about your problem rather than your (non) solution, we might have been able to say more.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I just asked because maybe exist some project that already do that.

Comment: @EdgarPavão There might, but I'm sure it has a hefty price on it too. But in any case, it would be script, and very limited.